# Change add to cart redirects

Tags: frontend, redirect, magento-2.1.3

This is how my **add to cart** functionality **works** :

I have a **quick link** for each products on **home page.** When I click on the link, I get a **popup** by **ajax** with add to cart functionality.

On submit, it adds product to cart and **redirects** to the **ajax url** through which the popup was generated which is wrong. Basically the popup is on home page and I want it to redirect to home page.

Now the problem is that **Checkout** module takes **referral url** which is ajax url and redirects to it.

The **Cart controller** has all the functions as **protected** so I am not even able to use **interceptors**.

So basically I could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method called `getBackUrl` in `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart` that checks for `return_url` parameter. You could try adding a hidden input to your form with the name `return_url` and value of the homepage url.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to create a custom controller that extends `Cart\Add` and modify the `execute` method so that it redirects to the homepage. Then change the `action` of your form from `checkout/cart/add` to `your/controller`.